# Using Javascript to show/hide elements depending on content in div

Tags: javascript, html

I am relatively inexperienced with JavaScript, and I'm working on a project that's turned into a real trial by fire for me, but hopefully this is a question that has a stupidly straightforward answer.

I'm trying to write a script that will show/hide different links on a page by changing the display style of different links.

I want to use a div element and have different links available if the user drags different images into the div.  The links are in clickable pictures.

Example-

I want this linked element 'link' to be displayed only if "First_Image.png" has been dragged and dropped into div2:

```
<a id='link' href='link.html' style='display: none;'><IMG src="../Image.png"></a>
```

My div id is "div2", and it starts out empty as such:

```
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Images on the page are set up as:

```
    <IMG src="First_Image.png" id="First_Image" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

There are several such droppable images on the page.  My attempt at this script is:

```
<script>    
if (document.getElementById("div2").getElementsByTagName('img') == "First_Image")
   document.getElementById('link').style.display = 'block';
return (false);
</script>
```

I'm not sure if my problem is that I'm not getting the information I think I am from the image in the div, or if my simple if statement isn't doing what I think it's doing. :/

Comment: your script is wrong right? where this call? you're comparing ume DOM element with a string?

Comment: Correct, the rest of my page works fine it's just the script. 

I was hoping to get it to change the display style, and either I'm referencing the object I'm looking for in the wrong way, or I'm trying to change the display style in a way that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the values from the attributes (as the `src` is an attribute). You can try out Element.getAttribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute

```
document.getElementById("div2").getElementsByTagName("img").getAttribute("src");
```

Step by step would be:

```
var id = document.getElementById("div2");
var elem = id.getElementsByTagName("img");
var atr = elem.getAttribute("src");
/* for comparing */
if(atr == "First_Image.png") {
  return false;
}
```

This will produce this: **First_Image.png**. And also, write this:

```
return false; /* not (false) */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your comparison

```
if (document.getElementById("div2").getElementsByTagName('img').src.indexOf("First_Image") > -1)
```